# Magnitude and phase of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

I did a Discrete time Fourier transform of the following signal:

$$x[1]=4\quad x[-1]=4$$

The result is
$$4e^{j\omega}-4e^{-j\omega}$$

We were supposed to draw the magnitude and phase graph of this complex function.

Firstly, I turned it into complex sine using $\sin(\alpha)=\frac{e^{j\alpha}-e^{-j\alpha}}{2j}$:

$$4e^{j\omega}-4e^{-j\omega} = 8j\sin(\omega)$$

I then turned it into magnitude and phase parts:

$$8j\sin(\omega) = 8\sin(\omega)\cdot e^{j\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

From this, it is apparent that the magnitude is:

$$8\sin(\omega)$$
And the phase is:
$$e^{j\frac{\pi}{2}} \implies\frac{\pi}{2}$$

I was able to draw the graphs of both of these but for some reason, both were incorrect. In the answer sheet, the magnitude was drawn in absolute value. And the phase was not on $\frac{\pi}{2}$ on the entire graph (as the function would suggest), but only on the positive part of the x axis. I don't know what I did wrong. The following image was in the answer sheet:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the real-valued sine function isn't positive for all real $\omega$.

$$|8j\sin{\omega}|=8 |\sin{\omega}|$$

Then,

$$8j\sin{\omega} = 8 |\sin{\omega}| e^{i \pi /2}$$

And then you can break it into cases: when $\sin{\omega}>0$, you get your answer, and when $\sin{\omega}<0$, $|\sin{\omega}|=-\sin{\omega}$, and that $(-1)$ gets the argument shifted by $\pi$ (remember to rewrite it in the principal argument later).

Comment: Hmm, I understand the magnitude part now, but I am not sure about the argument part. The resulting function has a constant phase shift so I don't see why it changes on negative parts. To me, it's as if we had an ordinary sine wave $\sin(2x+\pi)$, which also gets negative, but the phase shift is always $\pi$. I know I am wrong, I just don't see the reason why.

Comment: For an in depht explanation, you should check again how the principal argument function is defined, because it's not just $\arctan(y/x)$, it's a picewise defined function depending in which quadrant lies the complex number. In the second break up case, the complex number has no real part (meaning, it's zero) and its imaginary part is negative, therefore, its principal argument must be $-\pi /2$.

Comment: check out this resource https://www.geogebra.org/classic/kcnmy2bs I hope it helps to visualize the complex quantity you're dealing with!